# Setting the same font size across multiple viewboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, viewbox

Let's say I have two viewboxes with two textblocks inside them. They both have the same Width and Height, but the text won't be the same length. How could I make them have the same font size, regardless of the number of characters?

Code example:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="vb1">
    <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
</Viewbox>
<Viewbox x:Name="vb2">
    <TextBlock Text="Some bigger text" />
</Viewbox>
```

Here's what I would like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place both `TextBlock` controls in the same `ViewBox`:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
        <TextBlock Text="Some bigger text" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

What Mike Strobel said makes sense; I'm not sure if you want to overlap the text or not. If not, then replace the `Grid` with a `StackPanel` to get an effect like this:

[image]

To place them side-by-side, you could play around with a `Grid` and setting column widths... YMMV. I'm not sure what else to suggest because I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
        <TextBlock Text="Some bigger text" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Note that the text blocks may need to be placed in a `StackPanel` or laid out in a way where they won't overlap.

Comment: OK, that helped me a lot already, I'm just having trouble with one more detail: How could I make the textblocks have the same width? I uploaded a picture to try to explain better the situation. I tried to create a grid with 2 columns with Width=1*, but no luck, and with a stackpanel it wouldn't respect the 50:50 ratio

Comment: I got it to work using grids. What I did was to create a grid with two columns, and set them to resize along the window. Then, inside the grid, I created the viewbox, and inside it I created the grid, with the width={Binding ElementName=columnName, Path=ActualWidth}. Dunno if there was a simpler way, but it's working for now