# how to make texts in two Viewboxes the same size?

Tags: wpf

In WPF, i am using Viewbox to make some text automatically resize. The problem is that the texts end up with different fonts because the shorter text will show up bigger.

```
<Grid>
    <!--grid definitions-->
    <TextBlock Text="short text" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tb2" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=tb3, Path=FontSize}"/>   <--HERE
    <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBlock Text="looooong text" x:Name="tb3" Style="{StaticResource txtNormal}"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

In the line marked by "HERE", i tried to bind the font size of one `TextBlcok` to another, but it doesn't work. I've also tried using `StretchDirection="DownOnly"`; while this does make them the same size, but also much smaller. I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609703/setting-the-same-font-size-across-multiple-viewboxes) and tried to put the `Viewbox` outside of the `Grid`, but this messes up the column width ratio as defined in `ColumnDefinition`.

So how to make texts in different `Viewbox`es the same size? Thanks!

Comment: Viewbox scales the rendered output of its child element, but does not change its properties like e.g. FontSize. It is generally a bad idea to put text elements in Viewboxes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the other TextBlock (short text) in ViewBox also, and Bind that ViewBox MaxHeight to the ActualHeight of the other ViewBox (long text).

```
<Viewbox MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=vb, Path=ActualHeight}">
    <TextBlock Text="short text" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tb2" />
</Viewbox>
<Viewbox Name="vb" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock Text="looooooooooong text" x:Name="tb3"/>
 </Viewbox>
```