# How to set multiple viewboxes the size of the biggest?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to display four viewboxes with borders and TextBlocks in them. Problem is that the TextBlocks are not the same size. I want to change the boxes size so i cant get 4 same sized boxes. Can i get some help pls ?

I already tried this [how to make texts in two Viewboxes the same size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860844/how-to-make-texts-in-two-viewboxes-the-same-size) but it didnt worked and my boxes pretty much disappeared

```
<Viewbox x:Name="FirstBox" Grid.Row="0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border Background="red">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock Text="short text"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="More text" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>

(This box four times with different text)
```

```cs
private void ChangeBoxSize()
{
    double first = FirstBox.ActualWidth;
    double second = SecondBox.ActualWidth;
    double third = ThirdBox.ActualWidth;
    double fourth = FourthBox.ActualWidth;
    double longest = first;

    if (second > longest)
    longest = second;
    if (third > longest)
        longest = third;
    if (fourth > longest)
        longest = fourth;
    FirstBox.MinWidth = longest;
    SecondBox.MinWidth = longest;
    ThirdBox.MinWidth = longest;
    FourthBox.MinWidth = longest;
}
```

I was expecting that the longest box will give it's width to the other boxes. In fact nothing happened

Comment: Why don't you use Grid instead ViewBox? At least you keep the size :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove the viewbox, put a grid and set the text alignment to a side. Thanks @taktak for the grid